# The best way to extract a large zip file in the background regardless of the template changing (or other external issues occurring) in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, zip

I want to upload a zip file that contains 1 GB or more image data. I have a function that renders a basic Django template that uploads the zip file in the server and then later extracts it using the zipfile module and stores these images.

My only worry is that when the user suddenly moves around the site or a network error (or some other external issue) occurs, the function gets interrupted and the extraction, as well as the database storage progress, stops. In short, duplication occurs.

If I try to re-run the function again, the 'already stored' images get stored again and later saved to the model. I am not sure how to proceed with the file extraction and storage once the python function gets interrupted.

What should I do?

This my code so far:

```
def upload(path, id):
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(path, mode='r', allowZip64=True) as file:
            document = Mymodel.objects.get(id=id)
            directory_to_extract = f"media/{document.path}"
            file.extractall(directory_to_extract)
    except zipfile.LargeZipFile:
        print("File size is too large.")
        return 0 #returns an error
    finally:
        file.close()
        os.remove(path)
```

**Note:**

1. The parameter 'path' is the temporary file path moved to the stored path in the directory.
2. The parameter 'id' is the zip file id that gets stored in the model along with its properties like size, desired path, etc before the extraction of its subdirectories takes place.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I feel threading could be a good use case here.

```
def upload(path, id):
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(path, mode='r', allowZip64=True) as file:
            document = Mymodel.objects.get(id=id)
            directory_to_extract = f"media/{document.path}"
            file.extractall(directory_to_extract)
    except zipfile.LargeZipFile:
        print("File size is too large.")
        return 0 #returns an error
    finally:
        file.close()
        os.remove(path)

thread = Thread(target=upload, args=(/path/, 3))
thread.start()
thread.join()
```